# Convert number to tuple (latin) name

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Wikipedia defines names for tuples (multiples) of specific length (up to 31 and some significant others afterwards) at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple#Names_for_tuples_of_specific_lengths.

For example:

- 1 = single
- 2 = double
- 3 = triple
- 4 = quadruple
- 5 = quintuple
- 6 = sextuple

Is there an easy way in JavaScript (specifically Ember) to convert from a number to the named tuple. So I could do something like

```
console.log(numberToNamedTuple(5)); // quintuple
```

Here is my existing code:

```
  let tuples = [
    '0',
    'Single',
    'Double',
    'Triple',
    'Quadruple',
    'Quintuple',
    'Sextuple',
    'Septuple',
    'Octuple',
    'Nonuple',
    'Decuple',
    'Undecuple',
    'Duodecuple',
    'Tredecuple',
    'Quattuordecuple',
    'Quindecuple',
    'Sexdecuple',
    'Septendecuple',
    'Octodecuple',
    'Novemdecuple',
    'Vigintuple',
    'Unvigintuple',
    'Duovigintuple',
    'Trevigintuple',
    'Quattuorvigintuple',
    'Quinvigintuple',
    'Sexvigintuple',
    'Septenvigintuple',
    'Octovigintuple',
    'Novemvigintuple',
    'Trigintuple',
    'Untrigintuple'
  ];

  return tuples[index];
```

Obviously this is not very extensible and I have to manually put an entry into the array for every number in the world that might be entered. Is there an existing JS function I should be using instead or something I have overlooked perhaps?

Please note this question is related to the mathematic / real world definition of a tuple rather than the programming use of tuples as per python and other languages.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: This is not built into Javascript, and any library you use would probably do exactly what you have, so not worth using. Unless you can find a consistent pattern to generate the tuple, and based on your code i cant see one, I would stick with what you have.

Comment: @PatsyIssa Seriously? I've not asked anybody to recommend a book, tool, software library or tutorial etc. I'm asking a specific objective question and if there is an existing Javascript function that I could use or anybody can think of a better way of doing it. This is a far-cry from the "can anybody recommend a good book on ..." type of question that the off-topic rule was clearly designed to address. If we apply your logic then we should close virtually all the questions on this site.

Comment: quote: ` Obviously this is not very extensible ` — what's not extensible about this? if you want to support more 'tuples' don't you just add them to the list? how could it be any more extensible?

Comment: @ChristopherMilne I meant without having to manually add each entry. Perhaps "extensible" was the wrong word. "Scalable" might have been a better choice.